# Как передать post и get запрос через php?

Tags: post, php, get

Как передать post и get запрос одновременно  через php?

Comment: Через curl можно, главное чтобы модуль был подключен. [CURL и реализация POST-запросов](http://parsing-and-i.blogspot.ru/2009/10/curl-post.html).

Comment: Никак.

Comment: @exec, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score -1):

Просто прописать в акшн путь с get параметрами

```
<form action="addres.php?my_get_data=here" method="POST">
    <input name="first" type="text" value="data">
    <input name="send" type="submit">
</form>
```